# How to get value of selected item from dropdown in jquery UI tabs content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, yii

I am using jquery UI tabs and I have text filed and dropdown to select in tab's content, I am getting the value from text field but not from dropdown select item, can any one please help me, my project is in yii

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Vertical Tabs functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  .ui-tabs-vertical { width: 55em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav { padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em; float: left; width: 12em; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li { clear: left; width: 100%; border-bottom-width: 1px !important; border-right-width: 0 !important; margin: 0 -1px .2em 0; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a { display:block; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active { padding-bottom: 0; padding-right: .1em; border-right-width: 1px; }
  .ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel { padding: 1em; float: right; width: 40em;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $model->name;?>
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Basic Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Report</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Set schedule</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
    <?php echo 'la la';?>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Content heading 2</h2>

  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'message-form',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('target'=>'_blank'),
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
        <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model_report_form); 
                ?>
        <table class="table">

            <tr>
                <td><?php
                    echo $form->labelEx($model,'month');
                    $months = array(
                        '01'=>'January', 
                        '02'=>'February',
                        '03'=>'March', 
                        '04'=>'April',
                        '05'=>'May', 
                        '06'=>'June',
                        '07'=>'July', 
                        '08'=>'August',
                        '09'=>'September', 
                        '10'=>'October',  
                        '11'=>'November', 
                        '12'=>'December',
                        );
                    //$stat = array('13' => Yii::t('month','ALL'));
                    echo $form->dropdownlist($model_report_form,'month',$months,array('empty' => '--Select a month--'));                
                //echo $form->textField($model,'end_date'); 
                ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $form->labelEx($model_report_form,'year');   
                $years = array(
                        '2016'=>'2016', 
                        '2017'=>'2017',
                        '2018'=>'2018', 
                        '2019'=>'2019',
                        '2020'=>'2020', 
                        '2021'=>'2021',
                        '2022'=>'2022', 
                        '2023'=>'2023',  
                        '2024'=>'2024', 
                        '2025'=>'2025',
                        );
                    //$stat = array('3000' => Yii::t('year','ALL'));
                    echo $form->dropdownlist($model_report_form,'year',$years,array('empty' => '--Select a year--')); 

                //echo $form->textField($model,'end_date'); 
                ?></td>


            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model_report_form, 'employee',array('value'=>$model->employee_id)); ?>
                <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model_report_form, 'report_type',array('value'=>'1')); ?>
            </tr>
        </table>




    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Get Report',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block')); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Comment: When are you trying to get the value? Once the form is submitted with PHP?

Comment: Where your form is submitted, do `print_r($_POST)`. Do you see the drop down values in there?

Comment: yes! I have used it but I do not get any result for slection, what ever I have solved it using ajax, and off course thanks for your time

Comment: Glad you solved it. Have a good weekend :)